# Opening documents inside a website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flash, docx

I want to know is there any flash viewer which i can embed on my website, for opening word, pdf files?

or is there anything else that i can put on my php website, that can view the document

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Google's docs Viewer: https://docs.google.com/viewer

It can handle most Office files, as well as PDF. It's not an unbranded solution, but it's probably the best you'll find.